# Is it possible to hide the Yandex logo from map in Android?

Tags: android, yandex-maps, yandex-mapkit

There is no method in the documentation that hides the logo from the map.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **MapKit terms of use**
>
> 3. You are not allowed to hide the Yandex logo
>
> The Yandex logo should always be visible on the map. Do not hide the
>   logo behind other objects.